# how to add two buttons in the same column of a row in table layout?

Tags: android, button, tablelayout, tablerow

I have a table layout wher i am displaying values from my database i have seven columns for that table..
i am adding rows to the table layout programmatically adding the data is fine..m doing that by using textviews..but in my seventh column i need to add two buttons..i need the two buttons in the same column and one beside the other....m able to display only one button..how do i display two buttons in one row in the same column??? Is it possible to do that??
Please help!! 
Thanks!

Here's how i am adding rows programmatically:

```
do
        {
            tr=new TableRow(this);
            tr.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            firstCol=new TextView(this);
            firstCol.setText("0");
            firstCol.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            firstCol.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            tr.addView(firstCol);

            secondCol=new TextView(this);
            secondCol.setText(lead.getString(index0));
            secondCol.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            secondCol.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            tr.addView(secondCol);

            thirdCol=new TextView(this);
            thirdCol.setText(lead.getString(index1));
            thirdCol.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            thirdCol.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            tr.addView(thirdCol);

            fourthCol=new TextView(this);
            fourthCol.setText(lead.getString(index2));
            fourthCol.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            fourthCol.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            tr.addView(fourthCol);

            fifthCol=new TextView(this);
            fifthCol.setText(lead.getString(index3));
            fifthCol.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            fifthCol.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            tr.addView(fifthCol);

            sixthCol=new TextView(this);
            sixthCol.setText(lead.getString(index4));
            sixthCol.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            sixthCol.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            tr.addView(sixthCol);

            seventhCol=new Button(this);
            seventhCol.setBackground(getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.circ));
            tr.addView(seventhCol);

            lead_table.addView(tr);

            tr.setOnClickListener(this);

        }while(lead.moveToNext());
```

Here is the table layout:

```
 <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/lead_table"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:stretchColumns="*" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/bgbtn"
                android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                android:text="Lead ID"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/bgbtn"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:text="Name"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/bgbtn"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:text="Mobile"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/bgbtn"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:text="Product"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/bgbtn"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:text="Value"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/bgbtn"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:text="Status"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/bgbtn"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:text="Action"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        </TableRow>


    </TableLayout>
```

Comment: Think logically, How can you display 2 buttons in the same column in one row, if you want to let them be displayed side by side ? It does not make any logical sense. You can how ever, keep 2 buttons in two different columns in the same row and display them as side by side entities .

Comment: @TheDarkKnight but i have a header for that column and those two buttons need to cum under that column!

Comment: Okay, so what you have to do here is add  two columns inside that column and then add the buttons to those columns. Let me try that . I will get back to you . Or you can follow Torben's solution as well, that will work also, i assume .

Comment: Post your activity_main.xml , so that we can see the table layout

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a `LinearLayout`, add the two buttons to it and then add the `LinearLayout` to the `TableRow`.